# cordova 6.5 inappbrowser 1.7.0 android not working but iOS works

Tags: android, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm completely dumbfounded by an issue getting inappbrowser to work on android. Everything works perfectly on iOS, but android does nothing. No blank window open, no error message, nothing. Any help would be much appreciated!

js call:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
  console.log('device ready!');
 window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}

var ref = null;
ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(oktaURL, '_blank', 'hidden=no,location=yes');
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function (event) {
    console.log('loadstart');
});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
    console.log('loadstop');
});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function () {
    console.log('exit ');
});
```

When triggered, none of the console log in the event listeners fire. However, if I inspect ref, it returns "InAppBrowser { channels: Object }" with proper objects and correct references to which function called the inappbrowser, etc.

Executing manual on console

```
cordova.exec(null, null, "InAppBrowser", "open", ['http://www.yahoo.com', '_blank', 'location=yes']);
```

returns the same thing, no error, but also no window of any kind.
Note that I do see things firing in the source file itself when console.log in module.exports of inappbrowser.js

config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget defaultlocale="en-US" id="com.zscaler.apex" version="0.0.34" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <description>A blank project that uses Apache Cordova to help you build an app that targets multiple mobile platforms: Android, iOS, Windows, and Windows Phone.</description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">Apache Cordova Team</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>
  <access origin="*"/>
  <access launch-external="yes" origin="http://*"/>
  <access launch-external="yes" origin="https://*"/>
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="*"/>
  <vs:features/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"/>
    <icon density="mdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"/>
    <icon density="hdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"/>
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon height="180" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180"/>
    <icon height="60" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60"/>
    <icon height="120" src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120"/>
    <icon height="76" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76"/>
    <icon height="152" src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152"/>
    <icon height="40" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40"/>
    <icon height="80" src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80"/>
    <icon height="57" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57"/>
    <icon height="114" src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114"/>
    <icon height="72" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72"/>
    <icon height="144" src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144"/>
    <icon height="29" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29"/>
    <icon height="58" src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58"/>
    <icon height="50" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50"/>
    <icon height="100" src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash density="land-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png"/>
    <splash density="land-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png"/>
    <splash density="land-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png"/>
    <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png"/>
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="port-ldpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png"/>
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash height="480" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320"/>
    <splash height="960" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="1024" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768"/>
    <splash height="2048" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536"/>
    <splash height="768" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024"/>
    <splash height="1536" src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048"/>
    <splash height="1136" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640"/>
    <splash height="1334" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750"/>
    <splash height="2208" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242"/>
    <splash height="1242" src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208"/>
  </platform>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" src="https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git" version="5.0.6"/>
  <vs:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" src="https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git" version="0.8.3dev"/>
  <key>SocialSharingExcludeActivities</key>
  <array>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.AssignToContact</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFacebook</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToTwitter</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToFlickr</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToWeibo</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.PostToVimeo</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.TencentWeibo</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.Print</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.CopyToPasteboard</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.AssignToContact</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.SaveToCameraRoll</string>
    <string>com.apple.UIKit.activity.AddToReadingList</string>
  </array>
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="True"/>
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True"/>
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="True"/>
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True"/>
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.1"/>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1.2.1"/>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.5.0"/>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="4.1.0"/>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="3.1.0"/>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="~1.7.0"/>
</widget>
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, I have no idea what to do.  Could be the best idea is to downgrade to an earlier version of Cordova and the plugin? :/

Comment: @WillBrickner, downgrading cordova worked for you? I'm seeing a bunch of java error in the android studio device monitor that I hadn't notice before (because i primarily debug js side), issues showing "CordovaWebViewImpl:
Error loading url gap://ready; 
android content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent..."

Comment: I have no idea what that means. I did not try downgrading Cordova yet, I actually gave up for the time being as I need to finish other stuff. I didn't used to have this issue though which is the strange part, and I think Cordova was updated by mistake earlier but I'm not sure. Downgrading might help though. Let me know if you find anything that works for you, I need this fixed too.

Comment: Update: My problem was actually different (Android did not trust my site's SSL certificate), I never had to downgrade Cordova.  You may want to disregard my comments on this issue.